Black spots all over model in one project but looks fine on the other project
So I'm trying to do a render, but all I see are black spots all over the model and it looks ugly looking when I change to Cycles, but when I do another project (or scene) with Cycles it looks like it's just about fine with no errors on the mesh model. When I do Eevee with the messed up mesh project, it looks fine. Is there a way to fix this? I'm using Blender 4.2.1
The one with the black spots (Eevee and Cycles comparison):


The project and scene with no errors:


In this image, I used the same project that had the broken model, but a different scene and it looks fine compared to the scene I used before with the render camera. In Cycles, then Eevee:


I also notice there's some on the dress part of the mesh model. How do I fix it?
